# Haskell Gloss : direction vector to angle for rotation

Tags: haskell, rotation, geometry

For the Rotate function of the Gloss library in Haskell I need to provide it with an angle rather than a direction vector which I'm using for a moveable object, therefore I was wondering how can I convert this? I figured I'd use atan2 for this, but that gives me a really weird result (the picture that should rotate only rotates a little bit, then back, etc., and not arround its origin either).

What I tried is using the Rotate function from the Gloss Library plus the atan2 function for conversion from vector to angle:

```
Rotate (atan2 (snd dir) (fst dir)) pic
```

Where *dir* is a normalized Vector, initially (1,0), pointing at the direction in which the pic (a player's ship in this case) is pointing and possibly moving.

However this is not working properly.

If anyone could help me out it'd be much appreciated!

Best regards,
Skyfe.

Comment: `rotate` expects degrees, `atan2` seems to give radians.

Comment: Note that `atan2 (snd dir) (fst dir)` is `uncurry atan2 dir`

Comment: @user2407038: I think that `atan2 (fst dir) (snd dir)` is `uncurry atan2 dir`.  Note that `atan2` takes `snd` first, not `fst`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should just use [`argV`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.8.2.2/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Data-Vector.html#argV) to get the angle from the vector.

**Edit:**

You also have to convert this angle to degrees (from radians) with [`radToDeg`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.8.2.2/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Geometry-Angle.html).

Comment: Thanks! Now at least it's rotating, however it's not rotating around its origin, how can I do this?

Comment: @user2999349 Consider asking a new question if you cannot figure it out by your own.

Comment: I've figured it out thanks! Should've known it was rotating by the screen's origin, so I had to simply translate the image to that position, then rotate it and translate it back to its original position.